# How can I create a stacked bar chart in matplotlib where the stacks vary from bar to bar?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have a pandas DataFrame that looks something like this:

```
       year country  total
0  2010     USA     10
1  2010    CHIN     12
2  2011     USA      8
3  2011    JAPN     12
4  2012    KORR      7
5  2012     USA     10
6  2013    CHIN      9
7  2013     USA     13
```

I'd like to create a stacked bar chart in matplotlib, where there is one bar for each year and stacks for the two countries in that year with height based on the `total` column. The color should be based on the country and be represented in the legend.

I can't seem to figure out how to make this happen. I think I could do it using for loops to go through each year and each country, then construct the bar with the color corresponding to values in a dictionary. However, this will create individual legend entries for each individual bar such that there are 8 total values in the legend. This is also a horribly inefficient way to graph in matplotlib as far as I can tell.

Can anyone give some pointers?

Comment: You can just [customize the legend entries](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html)

Comment: I suppose that this is one solution, but I have to imagine that there is a more efficient way to do this. Nested loops seem like a poor option for making a chart like this.

Comment: This is just equivalent to the missing countries in each year having 0 value for that particular year, isn't it? So it's the same as an ordinary bar chart.

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your `df` first. It can be done via the below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': {0: 2010, 1: 2010, 2: 2011, 3: 2011, 4: 2012, 5: 2012, 6: 2013, 7: 2013},
                   'country': {0: 'USA', 1: 'CHIN', 2: 'USA', 3: 'JAPN', 4: 'KORR', 5: 'USA', 6: 'CHIN', 7: 'USA'},
                   'total': {0: 10, 1: 12, 2: 8, 3: 12, 4: 7, 5: 10, 6: 9, 7: 13}})

df2 = df.groupby(['year',"country"])['total'].sum().unstack("country")
print (df2)

#
country  CHIN  JAPN  KORR   USA
year                           
2010     12.0   NaN   NaN  10.0
2011      NaN  12.0   NaN   8.0
2012      NaN   NaN   7.0  10.0
2013      9.0   NaN   NaN  13.0
#

ax = df2.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]